# Unable to find .a wxWidgets libraries through Visual studio remote compilation during linking stage

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets, libraries, .a

I am trying to build and link a C++ application with wxWidgets as GUI remotely with Visual Studio to an Ubuntu VM.

WxWidgets docs are saying that I should use the wx-config command line flag like so:

```
`wx-config cxxflags --libs`
```

Linux can locate those libraries through that command. My guess is that the complete compiler command is sent over, so why is it not interpreted like it does locally?

On the Linux machine I'am able to build with the flag's in the compiler command, with Visual Studio there no libraries found.

Comment: It's really not clear what are you asking about. What is the meaning of the very first sentence? Do you intend building a Linux (Ubuntu) binary using MSVS?

Comment: Yes I am, with remote compilation. VS is copying the files and executes the compiler build command.

Comment: @JFr, you can't build Linux executable with MSVS. MSVS can produce Windows binaries only. Why can't you remote to the machine and compile?

Comment: @Igor Remotely I can, it’s just not finding the libs or does not interpreted the build command as it does locally. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @JFr, what I meant is to ssh to the box and build everything with standard Linux toolchain? As I said - MSVC does not know how to build Linux binaries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not support backticks in the command-line.

```
`wx-config --cxxflags --libs`
```

The command above in Visual Studio command line won't be interpreted as it would on a Linux machine.

When wxWidgets is installed on the Linux machine you can type:

```
wx-config --cxxflags --libs all
```

Which will give you the content of those arguments like so:

```
`c-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_stc-3.1   
-lwx_gtk2u_richtext-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_ribbon-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_propgrid-3.1 
-lwx_gtk2u_aui-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 
-lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1
```

The output can be used in the compiler/linker command of Visual Studio

After this change without using the wx-config flags i was able to compile and link my application.